# Django accessing url parameters in Form wizard in get_context_data() method

Tags: django, django-formwizard

I have the following code

---- urls.py ----

```
url(r'^(?P<city_slug>[-\w]+)/$',
    BookingWizard.as_view(),
    name='city_booking'),
```

---- views.py ----

```
class BookingWizard(SessionWizardView):

    def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
         context = super(BookingWizard, self).get_context_data(form, **kwargs)
         cities = City.objects.all()
         context.update({'cities': cities,
                         'city': City.objects.get(slug=kwargs['city_slug'])})
        return context
```

The problem is I'm getting key error trying to access `kwargs['city_slug']` in the `get_context_data()` method.

although I can access `kwargs['city_slug']` in the `done()` method with no problems.

Any ideas?

Comment: What if you use `self.kwargs` instead of the local `kwargs`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the kwargs using `self.kwargs`. This is because it gets set in the `as_view()` method of `View` which is a superclass of `SessionWizardView`.

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/base.py#L61-68